CodeMirror Editor with Editor.js: Enter Key Moves Cursor Outside of Editor
I'm integrating a CodeMirror editor within Editor.js, but I'm encountering an issue where pressing the **Enter** key causes the cursor to move outside of the CodeMirror editor and create a new block in Editor.js instead of adding a new line within the editor.
Here’s a simplified version of the code I’m using:
import "./code-editor.css";

export class SimpleCodeTool {
  static get toolbox() {
    return {
      title: "Code Editor",
      icon: `
        <svg width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M14.5 15L17.5 12L14.5 9M9.5 9L6.5 12L9.5 15M7.8 21H16.2C17.8802 21 18.7202 21 19.362 20.673C19.9265 20.3854 20.3854 19.9265 20.673 19.362C21 18.7202 21 17.8802 21 16.2V7.8C21 6.11984 21 5.27976 20.673 4.63803C20.3854 4.07354 19.9265 3.6146 19.362 3.32698C18.7202 3 17.8802 3 16.2 3H7.8C6.11984 3 5.27976 3 4.63803 3.32698C4.07354 3.6146 3.6146 4.07354 3.32698 4.63803C3 5.27976 3 6.11984 3 7.8V16.2C3 17.8802 3 18.7202 3.32698 19.362C3.6146 19.9265 4.07354 20.3854 4.63803 20.673C5.27976 21 6.11984 21 7.8 21Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </svg>
      `,
    };
  }

  constructor({ data }) {
    this.data = data;
    this.wrapper = null;
    this.editor = null;
  }

  render() {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    this.wrapper.classList.add("simple-js-editor");

    this._createEditor(this.data ? this.data.code : "");

    return this.wrapper;
  }

  _createEditor(code) {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("code-editor-container");

    const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    container.appendChild(textarea);

    if (typeof CodeMirror !== "undefined") {
      this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
        mode: "javascript",
        theme: "dracula",
        lineNumbers: true,
      });

      if (typeof code === "string") {
        this.editor.setValue(code);
      } else {
        console.error("Code data is not a string:", code);
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editor.focus(); // Ensure the editor is focused after rendering
        this.editor.setCursor({
          line: 0, // Set to the desired line
          ch: 0    // Set to the desired character position
        });
      }, 0);

      textarea.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior
          this.editor.execCommand("newlineAndIndent"); // Handle newline within CodeMirror
        }
      });

      // Optionally adjust the height of the editor container
      this.editor.on("change", () => {
        this._adjustHeight(container);
      });
    } else {
      console.error("CodeMirror is not defined.");
      return;
    }

    this.wrapper.appendChild(container);
  }

  _adjustHeight(container) {
    const editorHeight = this.editor.getScrollInfo().height;
    container.style.height = Math.min(650, Math.max(650, editorHeight + 20)) + "px";
  }

  save(blockContent) {
    return {
      code: this.editor.getValue(),
    };
  }
}

.simple-js-editor {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #282c34; /* Background color for the editor */
}

.code-editor-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.CodeMirror {
  font-family: "Fira Code", monospace;
  height: auto;
}

Problem:
When I press **Enter** in the CodeMirror editor, the cursor moves outside the editor and creates a new block in Editor.js instead of adding a new line within the CodeMirror editor.
Expected Behavior:
Pressing **Enter** should add a new line within the CodeMirror editor, not affect the Editor.js block or move the cursor outside of the editor.
Steps to Reproduce:

Integrate CodeMirror editor into Editor.js using the code above.
Click into the CodeMirror editor and press Enter.

What I’ve Tried:

Used e.preventDefault() to stop the default behavior.

Used CodeMirror.execCommand("newlineAndIndent") to handle newline insertion.


Any Suggestions?
How can I resolve this issue so that pressing Enter only affects the CodeMirror editor and doesn’t interact with Editor.js?
Thank you for any help or insights you can provide!
